# How to make a typescript definition that depends on previous value?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, yargs

See this code for example:

```
var a
a.set('my-custom-value',55)
a.
```

In line number 3, How I make the IDE to be aware to the value in line 2, and offer auto complete to a string the defined by the end-user who is using the library?

I want that after I type `a.` I will see "my-custom-value" as an auto-complete option by VSCode.

I saw the `yargs` is working like that. If I defining a option or a positional parameter, later the IDE offer me what I choosed.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with an [`asserts` return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), which is possible because Typescript supports control-flow type narrowing:

```
class Foo {
    setKey<K extends PropertyKey, V>(k: K, v: V): asserts this is Record<K, V> {
        (this as any)[k] = v;
    }
}

let foo: Foo = new Foo();
// foo. completes as foo.setKey

foo.setKey('bar', 23);
// now foo. completes as foo.bar or foo.setKey
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXoQKYBcBpXATwB5DpcAPfXAOwBMYAFAJ3gAdc38TiSAGmgA1AHwAKANYAuaIWEA3OSICUcyHl4x8ACwCWMQ9ABKuYPDaMKw8SgzZH0CXuORoYeiVUBtKQF1oAF5oRQBuB2wAXwwY9AwQAmgAM0Q5BCQQ+lwAdzhECVUI9AB6EpTEADpoCwBbTkS6GHdU+Eq8IlIMDFb2ggEJAHIAIzA2QeEAJgBmIowy6Hp4PN6a+HrG3GaYXtG2aEsKto6BDCA)

Answer (score 2):

Its actually possible! *Sort of*. We can use control-flow type-narrowing (thanks @kaya3) along with a generic type (`T`) to keep track of what keys have been set. However, due to the type *narrowing* can only *add* keys, not remove them.

Here is a working example map with `set` and `get`:
(see @kaya3's answer for a simpler example if you don't want a separate `get` function)

```
// Tracking map.
class TMap<V, T extends Record<string, V> = {}> {
    public static create<V>(): TMap<V> {
        return new TMap({});
    }

    private _data: T;
    private constructor(data: T) {
        this._data = data;
    }

    public set<K extends string>(key: string extends K ? never : K, val: V): asserts this is TMap<V, Record<K, V> & T> {
        (this._data as Record<K, V>)[key] = val;
    }

    public get<K extends keyof T>(key: K): V {
        return this._data[key];
    }
}

const a: TMap<number> = TMap.create();
a.set('my-custom-value', 55);
// a.get tooltip: get(key: "my-custom-value"): number
a.set('my-other-key', 22);
a.set('my-other-key', 33);

// a.get tooltip: get(key: "my-custom-value" | "my-other-key"): number
const x = a.get('my-custom-value');
const y = a.get('my-other-key');

const unknownString: string = 'mystery-key';
// a.set(unknownString, 101); // Not allowed b/c we don't know the exact string value.
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUCcEMGMGsCWA7A5qAttADgOgFCwA20AzqRALI4A8AagDQSgCmAHgC4vIAmFASi1gB7SDxqkOkFKiZ0AfKAC8oAN4BfRavyhdobAFcARkUSxQk6BzOhYkFlZb15ACgCUALiq0FanXoD7DgNIZFBkFgB3b2wXDTcAbn9ddXxk-WkAN0dQAH0eK2gvcCSA7CyckWRJSANYDlEXAo4iiDc-AICOAAtEUlx8wuVQZuhSvVT0wxMbUhYOGgBpVk5uPgspGVd4FgBPLxqZFa5eCmWAfnCWTJZIUC9FpmyiLzpPUDI5yA4KHr7Qf7gajYehMQQiMRLOSKABkEC06QCLj+-UGLQ+AiEonEj1ACjcAG0drsALrDZ7jFJpMrGUzmVDzJbHNYUYnCABm8JcxIe7zoHU6uiCITCKIGoyJexJlNAqUmVUkH2KwJoyAMGCMt0UKiBOFwdgcXHcSWguDmHBcAHIMLsALSwAySYQYW3PAwsS1MACsXsS+BAH1wDI4oAawiI1mwXmD3L2XgARDb7Y6Gi63Sx4+81RrbvhTearUnhD1brbiZ7QAAmSt+-PzQt24vdUvlpgAZjbfv9YFNwdDwnDkej9Z5oETdodTrT0CI7vjoAAPmOiyXIGW9pmvNnNZBCMJqiG2MNe-XrROU87XTP3Za-QqQ7tj0HTyvm2vy1376ADMh4MhhJEyAAMqbGgBygegKhnpItx2uWSQBnWFo-n+AHARBTAAIwAAyYYkoABgAcsWHxEEQAEsDwoBGMA5iRCwIz7paIaodEJYrHAIaHGgoDpgQQA)

`key: string extends K ? never : K` is a hack to prevent you from supplying a non-specific `string` to the map, which would kill the key tracking.

---

Old clunkier example using copy-on-write:

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEHsAcE8FpIDt4HcBOBLALgU1ALYCG0AdAFADGANkQM50SSoCyJAPACqi4AeeSACaMA3gF9QAXlDiAfDPKgloaAFcARtUyVQdbEWzbQldLgO4AFAEoAXE1Yc5C5S9Cnsq9ElBJcqe2zQFuJWANyKymLkEUrQWABu5qAA+oIGRHac4S5xmIl4xsh66KqU2JDoFmn6mVbOrkrYABaYdKSp6VKg1UTZkdE5Glo6dLjY7ADSPPy4QozFmEgA5gA0oABqshYA1riwdhNridR267YBjqAA2ruwoIugEwC6p6ASAGSgnPIiMa7unm8vn8UAcQQA8uoAFa4Mqkeh0TBLJDBP4NJQ3PYvUDHNGRUD0GTXW73bzPV5iNbNVrtHpWMJ-KJ-NSaIxLMaTaYCYSgW6QABmXy2twO504V2e9QamEFFgAhDs9qTQNS2h19PS8Q1muhmKAAKLoXWVADk4CISCQkGwoHZNqtvl4rX0SBtItAJtAAGpeXsGei3GNASqWmqepjYE8+kookzKEUbUQuqDAqQTGY8NZwvGkHpQOoukRSKNsBYTQQEJRVHpIAR4MdVLgTWsAKwthnUMY+OxIVQEdS4dBddSkO1livwKs1usNpt1EBfSCQaiGaB2MfugBEE6n5RnRGojc3517-cH5AXUAI0EwnaHg+NdhHY5Ni2OmEE9YPjZNDPInZtHRpBTEg01McwsyoLpKGLMZxwQa0mkHL9qGbD0kOoahIF-cIF0NR9jFHOD5zATglxXTA11tOD3V8eJBxPXB6PQcggA)

Comment: Typescript does control-flow type narrowing, so a variable can have a different, narrower type at another point in the code than where the variable is declared.

Comment: @kaya3 Oh cool! I didn't know about that feature, updating my answer..

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you'll need to construct the type of object that you want. The following code allows you to do that.

```
class Builder<T extends object = {}> {
  private _obj: any
  constructor(t: T) {
    this._obj = { ...t }
    Object.keys(t).forEach((key) => (this as any)[key] = (t as any)[key])
  }

  public set<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V): Builder<SetResult<T, K, V>> & SetResult<T, K, V> {
    (this._obj)[key] = value
    return new Builder<SetResult<T, K, V>>(this._obj) as Builder<SetResult<T, K, V>> & SetResult<T, K, V>
  }
}
type SetResult<T, K extends string, V> = T & { [k in K]: V }
```

Use the code this way:

```
const a = new Builder({})
  .set('abc', 55)
  .set('def', 'name')
  .set('my_complex_variable', { ID: '1234', exists: false })

console.log(a.abc)
console.log(a.def)
console.log(a.my_complex_variable.ID)
```

The way it works is quite straightforward. Each call to the `set` function returns a new `Builder` object, which contains all the previous `set` calls. Note that each of the fields you access is strongly typed too: `abc` is a number, `def` is a string. There is some fairly nasty casting to the `any` type, but you could potentially clean that up if needed

Here's link to the [working code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCCuBLEATApgJwDwBVpoA8AXNAOxRgHsAjAKzWCOgF5oBvAXwD52BYAKGjQADhkQA3MCWgB9GrQBc0MKQCeAocEqkIRDPEaUMACiJKcASj6Ch0IgAtEEAHRy6LdtGfemHDbYB5OgYiZwBrNFUIUwtnADMjAFEwYHtjYwjVK2YeU0cYSGU1CwBtTIBdD1NlAuKyyPKLfz9+f2F4ahBEYGgINCIsAGl8YjIKXr1EUgBzABpoADUuDMilQfnJEHg0JQWLJQRkdGwAZX6AJTQIeBABnHn1xa4eADJoM6JL69vcB-ml6y2aB5JyueSlCoeTbbfxCDD9eAYUjQUhoADucCQqEwWA+Xxudz+T2WDlBbloVkKh2xpwuVwJv2gjyWr3edO+hKZ-y4zQELSIqmEaDZn3pP3uTJGJHIMF0Yhm3I8eDebGgZWgUyZ5V20BaAi0OiYYA8qIx1OOxk4TRszj6RGMAHIwNRgA75gBWd3WoS2-qO9BxN3QB2kMAAWzQDu9XjtjrDqhkWjDwhAhBkkjEztTQdVAEkACJKB0ARgATABmAAsQcITiIECUcTAID6uut+u0EEoqecIEo02MYGczuA1oNXZ7fYHQ4DY873bQvf7g+c8cTlGTqYI6bAmc6i4LFiAA)

Edit: I just noticed that if you use a variable name with hyphens in it, Intellisense won't bring it up as a suggestion if you use `.`. You can still get type checking on the field, but you'll have to access it using the indexer:

```
const a = new Builder({}).set('my-variable', 12)
console.log(a['my-variable'])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know what value you are going to be setting you could try something like this

```
let a: { value?: number } = {}
a.value = 55
```

but value will always be of type `number | undefined` because the typescript compiler doesn't know if you've set the value or not at any point in the code.